# Regular expression to match only parent pages in URL

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have a set of urls like this:

This will not match:

https://example.com/parent/child.html

These will match:

https://example.com/parent.html

https://example.com/parent.html/page/page-number

https://example.com/anything

https://example.com/anything/page/page-number

https://example.com/anything/sub-anything

https://example.com/anything/sub-anything/page/page-number

I have been searching a lot, but there is no solutions. I tried this, but it did not work as expected:

```
/^(https:\/\/example\.com\/[^/]+\.html|https:\/\/example\.com\/[^/]+\.html\/(.+?)|https:\/\/example\.com\/anything\/[^/]+)$/
```

The 'parent', 'child', 'anything', 'sub-anything' only consist of words, numbers, -, %

The 'page-number' is only number

What can be a good regex in this case?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Try it like this `^https://example\.com/(?!parent/)\S+$` https://regex101.com/r/NpRT52/1

Comment: Thanks, but the parents here are multiple parents. Means it is not a fixed parent. As I just edited in my question.

Comment: You could try matching either a file with an extension or match only directories where a dot is also possible `^https://example\.com/(?:[\w-]+\.\w+|[\w.-]+(?:/[\w-]+)*)$`  https://regex101.com/r/TZB0rM/1

Comment: Nice, thank you! This also works really well. I just made small adjustment: escape '/' and add '%'

`^https:\/\/example\.com\/(?:[%\w-]+\.\w+|[%\w.-]+(?:\/[%\w-]+)*)$`

Comment: If you use another [delimiter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) than `/` like for example `~` you don't have to escape the `\/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Changed `\w` to `[\w\d-]` to allow for numbers and dashes

Here is a very lazy regex that matches your test cases properly, but may not necessarily be usable beyond those. I recommend adding more examples of negative test cases if you want to attract higher quality answers.

```
https?:\/\/[\w%-]++(?:\.com)?(?(?=(\/[\w%-]+\/)[\w%-]+\.html)(?!)|.*)
```

If the parents can have a depth greater than one, for example: `https://example.com/parent/parent2/child.html` and you still don't want that to match, then the following should do the trick:

```
https?:\/\/[\w%-]++(?:\.com)?+(?(?=(?:\/[\w%-]+)+\/[\w%-]+\.html)(?!)|.*)
```

Explanation of the latter is the following:

```
https?       match "http" or "https"
:\/\/        match "://"
[\w%-]++    match any letters, numbers, '%', or '-'; don't allow backtracking (possessive)
(?:\.com)?+  match .com once if it's there, don't allow backtracking, don't store in capture group
(?(?=...)    if our positive lookahead matches
    (?:\/[\w%-]+)+    one or more groups of letter/number/'%'/'-' with a leading forward slash
    \/[\w%-]+\.html   followed be another forward slash, some letters/numbers/'%'/'-', then '.html'
(?!)         fail the match
|            else
.*)          match whatever is left
```

Here is the [regex on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xfBkl5/3)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems your regex doesn't work. Also, that is all of urls of my site's structure.

Edited: I tried, but it matchs everything.

Comment: Updated with link to Regex101 - maybe you can let me know which part isn't working; that will help me help you, as I made this using the PHP flavor on the site.

Comment: Oh, i know why it doesn't work. Because of this:

"The 'parent', 'child', 'anything', 'sub-anything' only consist of words, numbers and -"

When I put something-something, the regex will match all.

Comment: Edited to allow for numbers, letters, and '-'

Comment: Superb! Worked as expected, plus with the clear explanation, I can understand how it works now! Thank you so much!

Comment: Just an update, some of my urls also have '%', which will be matched all as well.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I can just add % to [\w\d-], like [\w\d-%]. I hope this is correct.

Comment: `\w` includes numbers, `[\w-]` is all that is needed (note underscore is also included). The `.` for TLD also should be escaped. Forward slashes also aren't reserved if they aren't the delimiter. So could become `~https?://[%\w-]++(?:\.com)?+(?(?=(?:/[%\w-]+)+/[%\w-]+\.html)(?!)|.*)~`

Comment: @ChuongLuong That would be correct but approaching a bad pattern. Hyphens should always be the first or last character in a character class. Otherwise you can create ASCII ranges.

Comment: Good catch on the `.` escape and the unnecessary `\d` @user3783243 - My answer has been updated to reflect these corrections. Also, I've added '%' to the character group to match the updated problem

Comment: Hi, just another question, in case I meet, what if all the urls will not start with: https://example.com.

Only start with the forward slashes, ie: /parent

How would the regex should be?

Comment: If you know it will not have 'example.com' in it at all: `^(?(?=(?:\/[\w%-]+)+\/[\w%-]+\.html)(?!)|.*)`  -- Otherwise, if it may or may not have 'example.com': `^(?:https?:\/\/[\w\d-]++(?:.com)?+)?+(?(?=(?:\/[\w\d-]+)+\/[\w\d-]+\.html)(?!)|.*)`

Comment: This version will matched the child url, not the other urls ...

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I forgot the 'g' and 'm' in the flag.